# How to input CRLF from keyboard in linux console

Tags: linux, console, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to test mail relay. It requires me to send CRLF at the end of DATA.

I can use toggle CRLFin telnet, or -C option for NC. But is there a way to input CRLF from keyboard in linux terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Using *vi*, create a file having these two characters

- `vi file` then <kbd>i</kbd> to enter *input* mode
- Hit <kbd>^V</kbd> followed by the decimal code of `^M`:
- <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>013</kbd> for `CR`
- then save `:wq` since LF is automatically added by vi

If you have it (or install it) doing

```
hexdump -C file
```

should  show

```
00000000  0d 0a                                             |..|
```

Now you can copy / paste or `cat` that file where necessary.

You could also prepare the file with other characters, headers that you `cat` one shot to your application.

Another, way is to install `dos2unix` (depending on your distrib), then prepare the file as necessary (ie without the `CR` aka `^M`), then do

```
unix2dos file
```

and all `0a` will be converted to `0d0a`

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would expect you can just press enter/return but if you really need to send CRLF then you can use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> for CR and 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> for LF

Comment: Unfortunately Ctrl-J produces same result as Ctrl-M. You can check it with command `cat |hexdump` and pressing ctrl-m ctrl-j ctrl-d. Output is 0000000 0a0a.

Comment: i think your testing method is flawed.

Comment: If my method is flawed, where and how? I hexdumped output of cat (which in turn receives it from keyboard input). Do you know better way to see what has been inputed?